Intercept network packets to userspace and transmit packets to application
I have one application which sends/receives packets using regular glibc read/write/send/recv.
I would like a second application to stop the packets reaching the network, receive the packet itself and have the ability to send packets back to the original application, so it receive's them via the usual glibc ::recv().
Is this possible in Linux?
I can write a kernel module but not sure if this would help communicate with both userspace applications?
I found this library:
https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/
but there's not many examples and I wondered if there's a better approach?
I've seen reference to Netfilter but I'm not sure if it can intercept and deliver to userspace, or only kernel modules?
Netlink sockets?

Of-course it is possible with Linux! What your second app demands should be achievable with iptables.
